# tool tip is not working inside table after adding data-container="body"

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

Tooltip is not working inside table

```
<td data-container="body">
  <span ng-show="false"> {{Plist.PriceLine}}</span>
  <a href="EditPlayer/PlayerList/{{Plist.PLID}}/Search" target="_blank">
    #{{Plist.PlayerID}}
  </a> 
  &nbsp;
  <span data-placement="top" 
    data-container="body" 
    ng-if="!Plist.Active" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" 
    title="This Team list is inactive">
  <a class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></a>
  </span> 
  {{Plist.PlayerTitle}}
</td>
```

I have already added `data-container="body"` to td but still I am not able to get the tooltip when I hover to span outside the table I am able to get the tooltip.

Comment: Are you trying to have tooltip on span or on anchor tab?

Comment: @Milind on span

Comment: Please provide a working plnkr/jsfiddle example showcasing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough.
However, one reason I see is that you have ANCHOR tag inside SPAN tag. Hence, ANCHOR tag eliminates title property of SPAN. 
To make this work, you need to add title property also to anchor.

Have a look on this:

```
<td data-container="body">

  <span data-placement="top" data-container="body" ng-if="!Plist.Active" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This Team list is inactive">

    Dummy text </br>
  <a title="This Team list is inactive" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle">This is anchor</a>
  </span> 

</td>

https://jsfiddle.net/milindbhatt3990/81a6dmtg/4/
```